# How can I write this function without using a modulo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I'm wondering if there is another way to write this function without using a modulo. I realized that I have another piece of code that requires me to click the #mail-wrap button and doing so messes up the number of clicks which affects this function.

It's just a simple switch. I'm not too good with conditionals.

```
$('#mail-wrap').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var c = 0;

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {
        $('#contact-button').addClass('project-button').text('Projects');
    } else {
        $('#contact-button').removeClass('project-button').text('Get in touch');
    }
});
```

Edit: Changed the question a bit. Sorry, the last one was too broad.

Comment: Why do you expect anything to happen? You're making an http request and doing nothing with the response.

Comment: open your developer tools in chrome or firebug in firefox and watch the network tab when you click on the link, there you can see if the ajax request is send.

Comment: Find yourself an introductory *Ajax with jQuery* tutorial then.

Comment: You didnt set site.url to an actual URL. So i think your ajax request does produce a js error and does not fire.

Comment: Why is the modulo your problem? You have some repeated code, but you could use the modulo to set one or two variables and use that in your code so you don't repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Boldewyn mentioned, most likely your problem is that you are defining a global variable `c`. But if you would like to avoid this variable completely you could check for the CSS-class of `contact-button` via the jQuery `hasClass` function, i.e.

```
$('#mail-wrap').click(function (e) {
  ...
  var contactButton = $('#contact-button');

  if (!contactButton.hasClass('project-button')) {
    $('#contact-button').addClass('project-button').css('width', '71px').text('Projects');
    ...
  } else {
    $('#contact-button').removeClass('project-button').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch');
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is interfering with other code, because you have implicitly generated a global variable `c`. Possible fix: Use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function() {
  var c = 0;
  /* rest of your code above ... */
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I updated the question. Basically it's because I have another piece of code that requires me to click the `#mail-wrap` button and doing so messes up the number of clicks.